# How to pass parameter with $location directive in Anjularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to Anjularjs. I tried to pass parameter with $location directive in Angularjs but console says "category not defined". What i am missing. Here is my code:

```
 $scope.editCategory = function(category) {
    alert(category.identity);
    $scope.resetError();
    $scope.category = category;
    $scope.catlist=category;
   $location.path('categories/edit').search({param:category});
```

};

I need to pass that category object in categories/edit url. 
It is not working. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please give your category object structure.

Comment: here is my object printed in browser console:                                            Object {id: "331e25d6-fbb5-42a5-b76d-fcac9b30a26e", trash: false, identity: "momo", description: null, menuItems: Array[0]…}

Comment: Is categories/edit' path defined in your route?

Comment: ya, I have defined it. And is redirecting also. But in edit page when try to access it, then it shows category is not defined message.

Comment: $location is not a directive, its a service. To share data between two pages\view use a custom service. Location can be used to pass simple querystring parameters. In your case you can pass the category Id. And on the edit page, load the category based on the id.

Comment: what type of custom service, any example..

Comment: Try use rthis: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router Here you have detiled information how to use parameters in URL: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
$location.path('/myURL/').search({param: 'value'});
```

will result in

```
 `/myURL/?param=value`
```

OR

```
$location.path('/myURL/'+ param1);
```

Please find [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) for more details

EDIT CODE 2:

here what I have tried.

HTML :

```
 <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
    <a ng-click="setParam()" href="javascript:void(0)">send query param</a> <br>
    <a ng-click="getParam()" href="javascript:void(0)">get query param</a> 

 </div>
```

JS :

```
 app.controller("testCtrl",function($scope,$location){

    var obj =   {
                    id: "331e25d6-fbb5-42a5-b76d-fcac9b30a26e", 
                    trash: false, 
                    identity: "momo", 
                    description: null,
                    menuItems : [0,12]
                }


    $scope.setParam = function(){
        $location.search({param: obj})
    }

    $scope.getParam = function(){ 
        console.log($location.search().param);
    }
```

})

otherway :

```
$scope.getParam = function(){ 

        var arrParam = $location.search().param;
        console.log($location.search().param,arrParam);

    }
```